# Issue adapting a function that takes as argument a column name

Tags: r, function, quasiquotes

I have the following function that has two actions: 1) takes a column character and converts all characters to lowercase, 2) removes any special characters that may be present in the column.

```
clean_string<-function(data,variable){
  data <- data |> dplyr::mutate({{variable}} := tolower({{variable}}))
  x <- data |> dplyr::mutate({{variable}} := gsub("[^a-z]", "", {{variable}}))
  return (x)
}
```

Here you have some dummy data to test it:

```
var_1<-rep(c("A","B%","C v","B","A","C"),10)
var_2<-rep(c("VAron","v Aron","muJER","Muj3er"),15)
var_3<-c(rep(c("1","0"),10),rep("0",5),rep(c("0","1","0"),10),rep("1",5) )
dat<-data.frame(var_1,var_2,var_3)
D.D_clean_1<- dat |>  clean_string( variable = var_1) |> clean_string( variable = var_2)
```

Now I want to be able to use this function with several columns. So I tried to pass as an argument a vector with the name of several columns.
First I tried to use the quasiquotation inside a loop:

```
clean_string<-function(data,variables){
  data.table::setDT(data)
  for (j in variables){
  data <- data |> dplyr::mutate({{j}} := tolower({{j}}))
  x <- data |> dplyr::mutate({{j}} := gsub("[^a-z]", "", {{j}}))
  }
  return (x)
}
```

But it does not work since I cannot produce a vector with the name of the columns without `""`)
So, then I tried to change the quasiquotation to `[[]]`. This supposed me to create a vector with the name of the columns as strings. However I got the following error:

```
Error: unexpected '[[' in:
"  for (j in variables){
  data <- data |> dplyr::mutate([["
```

Why any of my approaches are not working? How should I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr::across` and `...` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
clean_string <- function(data, ...) {
  data |>
    dplyr::mutate(
      dplyr::across(c(...), tolower),
      dplyr::across(c(...), ~ gsub("[^a-z]", "", .x))
    )
}

dat |>
  clean_string(var_1, var_2)
#>    var_1 var_2 var_3
#> 1      a varon     1
#> 2      b varon     0
#> 3     cv mujer     1
#> 4      b mujer     0
#> 5      a varon     1
#> 6      c varon     0
#> 7      a mujer     1
#> 8      b mujer     0
#> 9     cv varon     1
#> 10     b varon     0
```

Comment: Thanks! this is wonderful! ChatGPT has a looong way to go to beat stack overflow...

Comment: Stefan, may I ask you how can I adapt ```data_set$Fecha <- as.Date(as.character(data_set$Fecha),format = "%Y%m%d")``` To be used with across? I tried to do: ```dplyr::mutate(across(c(...), as.Date(format="%Y%m%d",.x)))``` But is not working!

Comment: Try with `dplyr::mutate(across(c(...), ~ as.Date(.x, "%Y%m%d")))`. You missed the `~`. And as your first code used `as.character()` it's safer to use `as.character(.x)` but perhaps not necessary.

Comment: Thanks stefan. One last question, why tolower didnt need ```~```

Comment: Hm. Not that easy explained. First it's not specific to `across`. If we are using a function which just takes a column as argument we can go without using `~` or mentioning the argument `.x`. That's the case with `tolower`. However, if we want to pass additional arguments to the function (like the pattern and replacement for gsub or the format in as.Date) we have to be more verbose. Here, the `~` tells `across` that we are going to use a so called lambda or anonymous function with an explicitly defined argument `.x`.